# CocoaPods spec does not copy bundle to the app

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I'm creating a private podspec (subspec actually) for my library that comes with a 3rd party `.bundle` file. I'm trying to copy the bundle by specifying it with the [resources](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resource) keyword like this in the spec

```
{
  "name": "MyPod",
  "source_files": [
    "MyPod/*.{h,m}"
  ],
  "preserve_paths": "MyPod/lib/**",
  "vendored_frameworks": "lib/ApplifierImpact.framework",
  "frameworks": "ApplifierImpact",
  "resources": "lib/ApplifierImpact.bundle"
}
```

but the `ApplifierImpact.bundle` is not present in the `Pods-MyApp-resources.sh` script.

what am I doing wrong ?

cheers,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was actually a path problem. It should be

`"resources": "MyPod/lib/ApplifierImpact.bundle"`

Answer (score 0):

> s.resource = 'Demo.bundle'

I do this already and this works fine. s.resources is for adding resource files and not bundles.